# Class specialization with a constant value in std::enable_if

Tags: c++, template-specialization, enable-if

I was writing a partial specialization for a class when the template parameter is derived from a specific type. My implementation is as follow -

```
struct base {};
struct derived: public base {};

template <typename T, typename=void>
struct foo {
    foo() { std::cout << "Version 1" << std::endl; } 
};

template <typename T>
struct foo <T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<base, T>::value>::type> {
    foo() { std::cout << "Version 2" << std::endl; }
};
```

This works as expected - when I instantiate `foo<int>`, the constructor prints `Version 1` and when I instantiate `foo<derived>`, the constructor prints `Version 2`.

Now, I was testing something and wanted to disable the partial specialization, so I just changed it to -

```
template <typename T>
struct foo <T, typename std::enable_if<false>::type> {
    foo() { std::cout << "Version 2" << std::endl; }
};
```

I just replaced `std::is_base_of<base, T>::value` with the constant `false`. But this time the compiler started issuing warnings like `std::enable_if<false, void>` doesn't have `type`.

Why does it behave this way? Why does SFINAE not kick in here? Why does the parameter to `std::enable_if` HAVE to depend on the template parameter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why does SFINAE not kick in here?

SFINAE stands for "*substitution failure is not an error*". If your argument to `std::enable_if` is not dependent, then there is no substitution and so it makes sense that it wouldn't apply.

Specifically the standard says the program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required, if

> a hypothetical instantiation of a template immediately following its definition would be ill-formed due to a construct that does not depend on a template parameter, [...]

(from [[temp.res.general]/8.4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp.res.general#8.4)) of the post-C++20 draft N4868)

`std::enable_if<false>::type` is not dependent and ill-formed immediately following the definition of your template.

Comment: As a follow-up I'd tend to use `sizeof(T) == 0`. That's always `false` in standard-compliant code.

Comment: Well, that answers the question! Thanks for referencing the language from the standard. Does this mean if I create a type `template <typename T> always_false { constexpr bool value = false}` and use `always_false<T>::value` inside `enable_if`, that would be okay? Or is this template also always malformed

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya There is room to argue whether https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp.res.general#8.1 still makes it IFNDR, but in practice it should be fine, yes.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts See comment above.

Comment: @user17732522 gotchya! I will use `sizeof(T) == 0`. Hopefully nowhere in the standard it says that size of type cannot be 0.

Comment: Okay sure, technically it's ill-formed, and you wouldn't want to leave completed code like that (as mentioned in the question it was temporary for testing purposes), but "no diagnostic required" is because in practice, requiring the compiler to check that in every template definition is prohibitively expensive, and no implementation I know of will explicitly disallow it.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Oh, I see! I guess as a final attempt at standard compliant, I could use `std::is_same<a_sentinel_type_nobody_should_use, T>::value` so that it even compiles. And yes, wouldn't leave this in the codebase anyway, it was just for testing something